# Visual Studio 2015 does not recognize typescript

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I have an angular2 project and want to edit with visual studio 2015.
Typescript extension is installed for visual studio 2015 as you can see on the picture.
[image]

Then I open the project as follow:

[image]

And visual studio 2015 does not recognize typescript file extension and the code:
[image]
[image]

Do I miss any plugins?

Comment: Is this really a web site or is it infact web application? You opened it with open web site and not open project. Old style web sites are not build in the same way a web application is, not sure if you can use typescript in those.

Comment: It is a web application but is not based on ASP.NET. I brought the book ng-book2 and want to edit sample app, so I open it with visual studio.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not a web application and you don't know the difference between web site and web application. The icon shown in the solution explorer (globe) also confirms this. What you should do is create a new web application - File - New Project - Web - ASP.NET Web Application. Add the items from the example project on that with Add existing item and try again.

Comment: I highly recommend using the latest visual studio 15 release (currently preview 3), and following these instructions https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Web Application based on ASP.NET and as long as you have the TypeScript extension install you will have more success.